# Actor good practice?

Tags: scala, coding-style, akka

I have an akka actor system running using scala. Now I need to configure multiple devices in parallel so I have a `Manager` actor that manages all those configuration tasks. To actually configure them he will spawn a `Worker` actor per configuration so that they run concurrently or parallel. Now the `Worker` actor doesn't really need to receive messages from the manager during the configuration he only needs to do his thing and then report that he has finished back to the `Manager`.

Now the question is do I pass the instructions and the `ActorRef` of the `Manager` in the constructor of the `Worker` or do I create it and then send it a message like `Do(action: => Unit)` and it will then reply to `sender` upon completion? Is there a convention how to do this or is one considered good practice?

**EDIT**: As Vladimir Matveev reminded me the reference to the `Manager` is not a problem as it is already known through the hierarchy in `context.parent`. That leaves only the question of how to pass the work to the `Worker`.

Comment: If `Manager` spawns workers directly, you do not need to pass `Manager` reference to them. Workers can use `context.parent` to access `Manager` `ActorRef`.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Oh yeah thats true. But what about the work they should do? Also is `context.parent` still the `Manager` if I spawn in the future using `context.scheduler.schedule...`? I think it should be because it is a closure but I am not sure about that.

Comment: If you use `context` inside an actor to spawn child actors, they will have this actor as a parent regardless of where you use `context` inside this actor. That's pretty logical, because, as you have said, `context` variable is just closed over, but it is still the same `context`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the work should be passed to the worker via messages. As this is the most safe way to communicate with an actor. It also enables you to use a dispatcher in front of the actor to split assigned work over multiple workers.

To make things clear, here is a short example:

```scala
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props

case class Start()
case class Finished()
case class Do(action: () => Unit)

class Manager extends Actor {

  override def preStart() =
    self ! Start()

  def receive = {
    case Start() =>
      val workers = context.actorOf(
        Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances = 5)))
      context.system.scheduler.schedule(5 seconds, 5 seconds, workers, Do(() => 1 * 1))

    case Finished() =>
      println("A worker finished work.")
  }
}

class Worker extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Do(f) =>
      f()
      sender ! Finished()
  }
}
```

After the manager gets started, it will create 5 workers and send them something to work on every 5 seconds. The Workers will execute the work and report back when they are finished. You can either use `sender` (always report to the issuer of the work) or `context.parent` (always report to the manager) to report finished work.